# My Java client-server program doesn't work

Tags: networking, java, android, webserver, 3d

I am trying to build a Java client/server project located at here: https://github.com/garlicPasta/dotServer
And the client as they suggest (Android) located here: https://github.com/garlicPasta/dotViewer

It is essentially supposed to transmit a 3D graphics file (say this .ply file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/dfhyy9xa5i9o2fz/testPLY.ply?dl=0) from the server to the Android client.

The server's executable `.jar` file and client's viewer (.`apk`) are all already there.  My problem is that I can not make the client/server program to work. I just don't see anything on the Android app and I'm not even sure if they are  connected. As suggested, I run their server with:

```
java -jar dotServer-all-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -f testPLY.ply
```

And on the Android app, I also go to settings to input the server's IP address (my laptop's IP address). Say `192.168.2.10`.

Maybe something is wrong with my settings?! Can someone test the project and tell me if they are able to run and see anything?

Comment: Did you check the firewall settings on the laptop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Setup**

The `.ply` file was placed in the same directory as the sever `.jar`. I did not experiment with different paths.

*Server Command (Pre-Built JAR)*:

```
    java -jar dotServer-all-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -f example.ply
```

*Server Address Format (Pre-Built Android Client Settings)*:

```
    192.168.2.10:8080
```

**Issues**

I was able to get this setup working. However, there were three issues:

1. Your example (ASCII formatted) `.ply` file does not seem to work with the Android client for some reason. I had to download a separate (binary formatted) `.ply` file in order to see it in the Android client.
2. This substitute `.ply` file only showed in red for me. I am not sure why it did not appear normally in the Android client but it was sufficient to verify that the server and client had a connection. Please see the screenshot of what it *should* look like in the notes below.
3. The pre-built server `.jar` defaults to port 8080 and did not seem to honor the `-p` (port) parameter.

   So you need to append `:8080` to the IP (e.g. `192.168.2.10:8080`) in the Android client Server IP settings if you are using the current pre-built server `.jar`.

[image: Android Client Server IP Settings Example Image]

**Notes**

To confirm that the Android client is connected, you can watch the
server output in the running window for that server. If the Android
client is connected, when you scroll around, the server will output
"Original" and "Compressed" messages in real-time regarding the data
transfer taking place.

[image: Image Of Server Output From Scrolling Through The Client Android Interface]

For reference here is what the `.ply` file I used *should* have looked like:

[image: Ply Viewer Ply File Screenshot]

---

**Software**

*[Potree](https://github.com/potree/potree/) ("free open-source WebGL based point cloud renderer for large point clouds")*

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did the whole thing before, but it looks like the point cloud was hiding somewhere in the screen!
Can you post a screenshot as well? It shows all in red for me.

Comment: Welcome. =) I updated my answer with a screenshot of the secondary .ply file as it should look. I had the same issue of it showing in red in the Android client as well. Sorry I didn't mention that originally.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I don't know why it looks all red. Their Github page shows the 3D models in color. One reason for not showing my .ply is because mine was ASCII formatted, while this one is binary.

Comment: The only thing I saw was that their example line to start the server included an .nvm file. Maybe .ply files are a weakness for the server/viewer for some reason. =/