# Problems in building a Github Java project

Tags: java, eclipse, compile, jar

This is a follow-up question from my previous [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1222500/my-java-client-server-program-doesnt-work). I was initially trying to just install and run with the executables, but now I am trying to build the project located at: https://github.com/garlicPasta/dotServer

It is essentially supposed to transmit a 3D graphics file (`.ply` binary format) from the server to the Android client.

The server's executable .`jar` file is already there, but my problem is about importing and running the project. After importing in Eclipse, I added many required .jar libraries as below and removed most of the error codes.

```
commons-cli-1.4.jar
commons-collections-3.2.2.jar
javatuples-1.2.jar
javax.json-api-1.0.jar
jply-0.2.0.jar
la4j-0.6.0.jar
nanohttpd-2.3.1.jar
```

But it looks like there is a `DataAccesLayer.MultiResTreeProtos` file which I can not find and shows the following error:

```
The import DataAccesLayer.MultiResTreeProtos cannot be resolved
```

I see a Google proto folder with `.proto` files inside the project; maybe these are required libraries but I'm not sure how they relate to the project.

Can someone with more experience help me to run the project and find out what is missing?

Comment: How does this question, differ from your previous [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1222500/my-java-client-server-program-doesnt-work), on this subject?

Comment: @Ramhound that was just to see the project installed from their executables, this one is building from source file.

Comment: In order to build the project, you will need the source code, to `DataAccesLayer.MultiResTreeProtos` otherwise you will be unable to build the project.

Comment: So this is not a library generated file? You mean it is missing intentionally?

Comment: "is it missing intentionally?" - I have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I am trying to build the project located at: https://github.com/garlicPasta/dotServer

First you need to read and take care of the instructions in the [README.md](https://github.com/garlicPasta/dotServer/blob/master/README.md) file:

> Dependencies :
>
> - gradle
> - goggle protocol buffers
>
> Build
>
> For building run the following command in the project root
>
> ```
> gradle build
> ```

The `dotServer` project is designed to be built using the [Gradle](https://gradle.org/) build tool.

The other dependency is [goggle protocol buffers](https://github.com/google/protobuf), so you have to download and install this as well. This will give you the infrastructure to handle the `.proto` files, which includes the **protocol buffer compiler** (more about this later):

> **Protocol Compiler Installation**
>
> The protocol compiler is written in C++. If you are using C++, please follow the C++ Installation Instructions to install `protoc` along with the C++ runtime.

---

#### I see a Google proto folder with .proto files inside the project

> maybe these are required libraries but I'm not sure how they relate to the project.

The `.proto` files are **Protocol Buffer** (aka. Protobuf) definition files, which are complied by the **protocol buffer compiler** (`protoc`) into `.java` files.

Once you do this you will have the "missing" `.java` files.

See [Java Generated Code](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java-generated?csw=1) for more information.

---

#### Building your project

You have two choices:

1. Use **Gradle**

   - Download and install the [Gradle](https://gradle.org/) build tool and use this to directly build your project, or
2. Use **Eclipse** together with **Gradle Tooling**

   - Download and install the Gradle tooling for Eclipse and use Eclipse to build your project:
   - Read [Using the Gradle build system in the Eclipse IDE - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGradle/article.html) which explains how to install the Gradle tooling for Eclipse and also import an existing Gradle project into Eclipse.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for your full description! I was guessing the `.proto` files might be something! Can you also help with compiling the dotViewer Android project? I import into Android Studio (with Gradle of course), but there are some incompatibility issues. I can post that as a separate question.

Comment: @TinaJ I know nothing about building Android, but feel free to ask a separate question and I will take a look.

Comment: sure. It was more than helpful! I will comment my new question here soon.

Comment: Here is my new question: https://superuser.com/questions/1223360/problems-in-building-a-github-android-project