# Problems in building a Github Android project

Tags: java, android, compile, github, android-studio

This is a follow-up question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1222975/problems-in-building-a-github-java-project). I was initially trying to just install the `.apk` executable, but now I am trying to build the project located at: https://github.com/garlicPasta/dotViewer

It is essentially supposed to receive a 3D graphics file (`.ply` format) from the server and visualize it.

The project is using Gradle, but when I'm trying to import it in Android Studio, I see the following message:

```
Error:Unable to find method 'com.android.build.gradle.tasks.factory.AndroidJavaCompile.setDependencyCacheDir(Ljava/io/File;)V'.
Possible causes for this unexpected error include:<ul><li>Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
<a href="syncProject">Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)</a></li><li>The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
<a href="stopGradleDaemons">Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)</a></li><li>Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.</li></ul>In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.
```

Can someone with more experience help me to import and run the project and find out what is missing for compiling?

UPDATE: There are two missing .`java` files which can be generated after compiling the `.proto` files.

Comment: Have you "installed" gradle using a similar process as here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26254526/manually-install-gradle-and-use-it-in-android-studio

Comment: @EricF Thanks, but Gradle is installed on AS and it uses a wrapper to automatically download the best version for it. Is there a need to manually install it again?

Comment: @EricF I did the process. Again having problems loading in AS with the same errors.

Comment: I was just making sure you installed it the "correct way" which seems like you did... Do you have java installed? to the right version required by this?

Comment: Yes. I'm developing apps for a while. This one is tricky for some reasons. Did you try importing the project on your end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After generating the java files out of `.proto` files, the project could compile perfectly on command line through `gradlew`. For Android Studio, I just imported the project as a new project and no more errors.